# android: volley keeps retrying when receiving 403 code

Tags: android, android-volley, http-response-codes

I also modified the `Retry policy` but it isn't working. here's the code:

```
JsonObjectRequest getReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, GET_URL, null,

              new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                     //bluh..

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Authorization", token);
                return headers;
            }
        };getReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    0,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(getReq);
```

sometimes it retrys up to 6 times. how can I prevent that?

Comment: try removing retry policy if you dont want to retry or reduce the `MAX_RETRIES` i.e. put 0.

Comment: the MAX_RETRIES is '1' by default.

Comment: and also pass `DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT` as 0 and try

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in "BasicNetwork" class (see commented out block)

```
  if (responseContents != null) {
                networkResponse = new NetworkResponse(statusCode, responseContents,
                        responseHeaders, false, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
//                    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED ||
//                            statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN) {
//                        attemptRetryOnException("auth",
//                                request, new AuthFailureError(networkResponse));
//                    } else
                        {
                        // TODO: Only throw ServerError for 5xx status codes.
                        throw new ServerError(networkResponse);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new NetworkError(networkResponse);
                }
```

This implementation violates RFC and caused huge server traffic in my case!